# Save value in join table - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add an amount value to my join table. Here are my models:

```
class Invoice
    has_many :invoice_payments
    has_many :payments, through: :invoice_payments
end

class InvoicePayment
    belongs_to :invoice
    belongs_to :payment
end

class Payment
    has_many :invoice_payments
    has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_payments 
end
```

I want to associate `N` number of invoices with a single payment. For each invoice, I want to save the amount that's being paid in the join table.

Here is my controller code:

```
 payment = Payment.new
  if params.has_key?(:invoices)
    params[:invoices].each do |i|


        invoice = Invoice.find(i[:id])
        invoice.amount_paid = calculate_amount_paid


       payment.invoices << invoice
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to set the amount on the InvoicePayment table. The field does exist on this table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new invoice payment object with each invoice, and save them in an array to attach the payment.

```
payment = Payment.new

if params.has_key?(:invoices)

  invoice_payments = params[:invoices].map do |i|
    invoice = Invoice.find(i[:id])
    InvoicePayment.new(invoice: invoice, amount_paid: calculate_amount_paid)
  end

  payment.invoice_payments << invoice_payments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create the `Payment` record and then insert the `InvoicePayment` records. That takes care of the required associations for you.

```
payment = Payment.create(payment_params)
if params.has_key?(:invoices)
  params[:invoices].each do |i|
    InvoicePayment.create(invoice_id: i[:id], payment: payment, amount_paid: calculate_amount_paid)
  end
end
```